# Model Parameter Setup Best Practice?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model that runs a query with a bunch of conditions in the SQL. As a result, the model needs to accept a lot of parameters, i.e:

```
this->model_name->method($param1, $param2, ... )
```

On the model side, I typically set this up as

```
function method($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL, ... )
```

Each of those parameters is optional, and use cases will vary around the app. So my question is: at what point (if ever) does it make sense to start passing these parameters to the method via an array, a la:

```
$params = [
'param1' => 'whatever',
'param2' => 'whatever',
...
]

this->model_name->method($params)
```

With the end goal being, I suppose, cleaner code, and less instances of `method(null, null, null, null, $param)` unless that's an okay thing to do.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question. If the array leads to cleaner more understandable code, do it!

Comment: One of the principles of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) is _"many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most answers have been supportive of the array method (which, generally speaking, I would also agree with), but I'll play devil's advocate and list some negatives:

**Documentation is less clear**

Most methods of documenting functions/methods will list the parameters of that function individually. For example, a function with a basic [DocBlock](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html#what-is-a-docblock) will look like this:

```
/**
 * A function that accepts an array of params
 * @param array $param_array An array of key=>value arguments
 */
function accept_array($param_array = array('key1' => 'first_val', 'key2' => 'second_val')) {

    var_dump($param_array);

}
```

Note how the DocBlock doesn't directly support individual parts of the `$param_array`, just the array as a whole. In contrast, listing all the arguments individually looks like this:

```
/**
 * A function that 'normal' params
 * @param string $key1 First argument
 * @param string $key2 Second argument
 */
function accept_normal($key1 = 'first_val', $key2 = 'second_val') {

    echo $key1;
    echo $key2;

}
```

This is also a problem if you expect your functions to be fairly self-documenting, as in the first example you're not required to actually list your expected arguments in the function itself.

---

**Default values may not work as expected**

'As expected' is probably a bit of a loaded phrase (and this is probably one of the more obvious problems), but take the following:

```
function accept_array($param_array = array('key1' => 'first_val', 'key2' => 'second_val')) {

    var_dump($param_array);

}

accept_array(array('key2' => 'a_different_val'));
```

Some may expect the var_dump to include the default value of `key1` and the new value of `key2`, but the *whole array is replaced*, meaning you will need to remember to set default values for each key manually in each function, like so:

```
function accept_array($param_array = array()) {

    if (!isset($param_array['key1'])) { $param_array['key1'] = 'first_val'; }
    if (!isset($param_array['key2'])) { $param_array['key2'] = 'second_val'; }

    var_dump($param_array);

}

accept_array(array('key2' => 'a_different_val'));
```

---

**No automatic filtering**

Listing the arguments the 'normal' way also gives you a built-in set of filters. Take for example this quick and dirty user search:

```
/**
 * We want to allow searching for users by user_id or email only!
 * @param array $param_array
 */
function find_user($param_array = array('user_id' => 0, 'email' => '')) {

    foreach ($param_array as $field => $value) {
        $this->db->or_where($field, $value);
    }

    $this->db->get('users');

}

find_user(array('first_name' => 'Joe', 'last_name' => 'Bloggs'));
```

Without manually adding some 'accepted keys' type validation on the `$param_array`, a call to the `find_user()` function can essentially use whatever fields it likes. The simpler version would obviously look like this:

```
/**
 * We want to allow searching for users by user_id or email only!
 * @param int $user_id
 * @param string $email
 */
function find_user($user_id = 0, $email = '') {

    $this->db->or_where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->or_where('email', $email);

    $this->db->get('users');

}

// No way for me to submit any other fields, they'll just fail when they get to the query
find_user('Joe', 'Bloggs'));
```

---

I accept some of these are a bit entry-level and there's probably many more that I missed (feel free to comment with more and I'll copy them into the reply with credit), but hopefully there's enough there to make people think twice about automatically using the 'array method' without thinking about manual validation and documentation etc.

Comment: I like your comments about documentation and default values, both which weigh in heavily on deciding which approach to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array of parameters provides a better option for self-documenting your code.

When I use many parameters, I often find myself using a style like:

```
// do_something_model($enable_option1,$enable_option2,$enable_option3) 
   do_something_model(FALSE,          TRUE,           FALSE)
```

where I carry a comment line with the parameter names to remind myself of how I am
using the model.

In such a case, using an array with meaningfully named keys provides a useful mnemonic.

More recently, I am also using more wrapper functions.  For example, I may have my
basic model method do get all my data from a table and this method will have a few
options.

I then define a new method that does a specific task and then invoke the basic method within it using the correct options.

**Footnote**
I find that if my methods have "too many options", it is better to rethink the purpose of the method and to break it up into two or more specialized methods that are easier to use.

Comment: Could you not do `do_something_model($enable_option1 = false, $enable_option2 = true, $enable_option3 = false)`? You'd obviously still need to get them in the right order but makes it a bit more readable without the extra comment line.

Comment: What you wrote is actually how I define my model. When I use my call my model methods in my controllers, that is where I use the comment-as-doc line.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the array version as well. Symfony2 also uses this pattern a lot, for instance in rendring templates, creating form classes and creating http responses in general. You just have to make sure you cleanly document all possible parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could go either route, but an array would definitely keep your methods cleaner.  It makes perfect sense to pass the parameters as an array.